# Why is Python giving an error when the command prompt is not?

Tags: python, git, batch-file, cmd

I have recently lost all of my data from a mistake with GitHub. I found a way to retrieve the information one by one. See here: [Why did the GitHub windows client delete all of my work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33832183/why-did-the-github-windows-client-delete-all-of-my-work) . I now have decided to make a Python program to automatically retrieve the data. I have done the process manually and it works fine. For some reason when I call the command: `git cat-file -t code`, it returns: `fatal: Not a valid object name code`. You replace code with the hexadecimal number. For example, `0921d007bc8ca0000a587181263cf4f8d4d38e31`. I do this in a for loop. I use

```
def runProcess(exe):    
    p = subprocess.Popen(exe, cwd="C:/Users/Ajay/github folder/", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=False)
    while True:
        retcode = p.poll() #returns None while subprocess is running
        line = p.stdout.readline()
        yield line
        if(retcode is not None):
            done = True
            break
```

to run the command prompt commands. Can someone please explain why this error only happens in Python and if I have done something incorrectly or if I should fix something.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this on windows? Also why are you making the code so so complaicted?

Comment: Yes this is on windows and I'm using the Windows command prompt.

Comment: why are you making the code so so complicated, do you just want the output?

Comment: I want to restore all that I have lost. I lost around 15 projects since this was my first time using git. I want to have an automated process to put everything back into classes.

Comment: I think `check_call(["git", "cat-file","-t", code],cwd="C:/Users/Ajay/github folder/")` will do all what your code is currently doing, what is code supposed to be?

Comment: What method is check_call()

Comment: It is subprocess, it does what your loop is doing it waits until the process finishes, it will also raise an error for non-zero exist status

Comment: I'm trying to read all the git objects stored in .git/objects/ and check if they are blobs. If they are, I read the info and save the file. I'm recovering the lost information automatically.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that thanks!

Comment: since you want to capture the output you should use [check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output). `check_call` can redirect the stdout of the process, but it won't read it from the pipe

Comment: @Pynchia I am getting a `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_output'` from `isblob = subprocess.check_output(["git", "cat-file","-t", line2],cwd="C:/Users/Ajay/github folder")` Should I import something else?

Comment: wow, that's weird, I have never had a problem calling `check_output`. I'm trying now, but I cannot reproduce your error (I'm on Ubuntu). Does it happen with `check_call` as well?

Comment: @Pynchia Oh, I figured it out. I'm on Python 2.5. It is only available on Python 2.7 and over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I used `shell=False`. If you change that to `shell=True` it works fine. When it is enabled it emulates the shell and works fine.